Possible to see rsync --info=progress2 when using rsnapshot?
Due to a troubling discovery that Timeshift is not saving extended attributes, and therefore creating broken restores, I've switched to rsnapshot.
rsnapshot basically creates a deduplication and versioning process for rsync, and seems to do a really good job. In the config files you set up for rsnapshot, it allows you to add in standard rsync args. For example, you can add the -X option to make sure rsync retains extended attributes (xattr).
In the config under the section rsync_long_args, I've added: --info=progress2
But it isn't showing me the usual rsync info progress which shows you an on-going progress like this:
71,256,901,358  99%   36.30MB/s    0:31:12 (xfr#173389, ir-chk=1000/361047)

Is there a way to get this to work with rsnapshot? I would prefer to see this rather than verbose output or an echo of all the commands being run (which are settings in the rsnapshot config).
